# Behaviour of const qualified function in C

Tags: c, function, constants, typedef

I was wondering if const qualifying function pointers makes any difference, since the only meaning i could think of is auto const-qualifying its parameters, which is of course not the case.

I created a little example file (test.c):

```
typedef void* vop(void*);

vop  fn;
const vop cfn;

int main(void){
    vop *p_fn = fn;
    const vop *cp_fn = fn;  // <- gives compiler warning
    vop *p_cfn = cfn;
    const vop *cp_cfn = cfn;
}
```

and ran

`gcc -Wall -Wno-unused-variable -c test.c`

which yields the following warning:

> warning: initialization makes '__attribute__((const))' qualified function pointer from unqualified [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]

So it is "ok" to assign a "pointer to const vop" to a variable of type "pointer to vop" which, if it was not a function pointer would yield something like:

> warning: initialization discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]

But now it warns for the opposite case. So the question arises: What is the difference between const qualified function pointers and those that are not const qualified?

---

Note: The [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/const) has the following paragraph:

> If a function type is declared with the const type qualifier (through the use of typedef), the behavior is undefined.

Is the warning i saw a result of that "undefined behaviour" or does this paragraph not apply in this case (and if not, in what case can it be applied)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function type cannot have any type qualifier on it, including `const`.  Doing so it [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

From section 6.7.3p9 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> If  the  specification  of  an  array  type  includes  any type  qualifiers,  the  element  type  is  so-qualified,  not  the  array  type.   **If  the  specification  of  a  function  type  includes  any  type qualifiers, the behavior is undefined.**

This declares a `const` function type:

```
const vop cfn;
```

And this declares a pointer to a `const` function type:

```
const vop *cp_fn;
```

Both of which violate 6.7.3p9.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the difference between const qualified function pointers and those that are not const qualified?

`const` has the usual meaning - one can be modified, the `const` one may not. Example:

```
void something();
void something_else();
int main() {
    void (*normal_pointer)() = something;
    normal_pointer = something_else; // all fine

    void (*const const_qualified_pointer)() = something;
    const_qualified_pointer = something_else; // error

    // for fun, let's aad typedef examples
    // similar with a typedef, if you want to
    typedef void functype();
    functype *pnt = something;
    pnt = something_else; // all fine

    functype *const cpnt = something;
    cpnt = something_else; // error

    // note that if typedef is already a pointer... then it's already a pointer
    typedef void (*functypepnt)();
    functypepnt pnt2 = something;
    pnt2 = something_else; // all fine

    const functypepnt cpnt2 = something;
    cpnt2 = something_else; // error
}
```

> Is the warning i saw a result of that "undefined behaviour" or does this paragraph not apply in this case (and if not, in what case can it be applied)?

Yes. `vop` is a function type. `const vop` is undefined behavior. `gcc` issues a warning and ignores the qualifier.

You may want to `const`-qualify the pointer itself instead, not the pointed-to-type:

```
vop *const cp_cfn = fn;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i actually just was curious about the case where `const` is placed before the asterisk. The question title might be a bit misleading. Should i change it? This answer will be a good reference for people who might stumble upon this question and actually want the "constant pointer".